# Character encoding in regular-expression substitution

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to substitute a regular expression with another pattern. More specifically I want to replace `$$ some_latex $$` with `$latex some_latex$`. I tried following.

```
In [22]: re.sub(r'\$\$(?P<pat>.+?)\$\$', r'$latex \1 $', "$$ x = \frac{2}{3}$$", re.DOTALL | re.U)
Out[22]: '$latex  x = \x0crac{2}{3} $'
```

The word `\frac` is converted to `\x0crac`. How to overcome this. I tried following also. It didn't help.

```
re.sub(r'\$\$(?P<pat>.+?)\$\$', r'$latex \1 $', "$$ x = \frac{2{3}$$".encode("string_escape"), re.DOTALL | re.U)
'$latex  x = \\x0crac{2}{3} $'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a regular expression; `\f` is a form-feed escape code:

```
>>> '\f'
'\x0c'
>>> len('\f')
1
```

The character is *already present* in your input, before replacements even take place:

```
>>> "$$ x = \frac{2}{3}$$"
'$$ x = \x0crac{2}{3}$$'
```

Double the slash or use a raw string literal:

```
>>> '\\f'
'\\f'
>>> r'\f'
'\\f'
>>> print '\\f'
\f
>>> len('\\f')
2
```

Comment: Now if I want to change `\\f` back to `\f`? `replace('\\\\', '\\')` is not working.

Comment: @Dilawar: The interpreter gives you a *representation*; a Python literal just as you would type it in. The `\\` is ready-escaped, it is *not* the value. If you use `print` you'll see there is just *one* backslash character. You don't have to replace anything.